# How to do dependency injection into my own classes in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

define a class like the one below.

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  post() {
    // want to send to the server by POST method.
    // like "http.post('/api/person', {name: this.name});"
  }
}
```

I want to use this class in each component, etc. as follows

```
const person = new Person('John');
person.post();
```

How can i achieve this?
Is such an implementation an anti-pattern to begin with?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That wasn't that Dependency injection is. Recheck the definition and it might answer your question.

Comment: Have a look to the way you could possibly use in Angular Static class and Static method ...

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new class, you won't have access to `http` because you can't Inject it. You have a couple of options:

- Manually pass HttpClient in the constructor of `Person`.
- Manually pass HttpClient in the `post()` function in `Person`.
- Create a Service i.e. PersonRestService:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonRestService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  public createPerson$(person: Person): Observable<number> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };

    return this.http.post<number>('YOUR_URL_HERE', person, httpOptions);
  }
}
```